# make a list of converted strings to variables

Tags: python, list, variables

I want to collect a list from a set of variables, for instance I do this iteration:

```
x=10
func=[]
for i in range(10):
    globals()['p%s' % i]=i**2+x*10
```

at the end I want to have a list of dynamic variables

```
func=[p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9]
```

How could it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Numbered variable names is a sign that you should be using a list, tuple or dict instead. For example, here you could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
x = 10
func = [i**2+x*10 for i in range(10)]
```

---

Or, for the example you mention in the comments (assuming you are using matplotlib):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = [[1,2,3], [3,2,1], [2,3,1]]
for i, datum in enumerate(data, 1):
    plt.plot(datum, label='line {}'.format(i))
plt.legend()    
plt.show()
```

Comment: I reckon there should be a way to make a list of variable names?!!

Comment: You can, but you should not want to. It will always be a pain to program with dynamically named variables, because it forces you to use awkward string formatting just to access the variable. Moreover it is slower than indexing into a list, tuple or dict. There are better ways to do what you want to do.

Comment: I am getting this error `TypeError: 'PathCollection' object is not iterable
`

Comment: Since that is clearly a different issue, please post a new question.

Comment: well, I didn't get an adequate answer for my original question, but I will do!

Comment: @Dalek It wasn't the answer you wanted or expected, but it was the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should seriously consider rewriting your code to us p[0], p[1], p[2] instead of p0, p1, p2; however, this should get you the same result:

```
x=10
func=[]
for i in range(10):
    globals()['p%s' % i]=i**2+x*10
    func.append(i**2+x*10)
```

Comment: actually it is just an example. I want to make a set of plots and legend at the end and I need to collect the variable names to do this  `p1, = plot([1,2,3])
p2, = plot([3,2,1])
p3, = plot([2,3,1])
legend([p2, p1, p3], ["line 2", "line 1","line 2"])`

Comment: @Dalek no you don't, you need to add a layer of abstraction. Instead of having 3 variables, you need to have 1 list (of 3 elements). Anytime you put a number in a variable name, think to yourself whether you could write that as a list instead. It'll be better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want func list to store variable not the value.

Try this:

```
x=10
func=[]
for i in range(10):
    globals()['p%s' % i]=i**2+x*10

for i in globals().keys():
    if i.startswith('p') and len(i)==2:
        func.append(i)

print func
```